# Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n^2+1)^n}{(-n)^n}$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find a series test to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n^2+1)^n}{(-n)^n}$ diverges.

I now it diverges because of the plot given by Wolfram Alpha, however, I'm having some problems finding a suitable test to prove that.

Since it is an alternate series, I'm trying to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n^2+1)^n}{(-n)^n}$ is different from zero, but I don't know how to solve this limit as well.

Comment: Take subsequence $m=2n$ and use comparison term $\frac {m^2+1}m\gt m$...

Comment: Hint: note that $(-n)^n = (-1)^n n^n.$

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ is convergent then $|a_n|\to 0$

Comment: A plot can never prove the convergence or divergence of a series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show that the geometric series is by using the Root Test.

The Root Test states that: [Root Test conditions for convergence or divergence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpHaP.pngsad)

Note that alternating term can be rewritten as shown here:

### $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n^2+1)^n}{(-n)^n} \ \to \ $  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(n^2+1)^n}{(n)^n}$

Then using the afore mentioned Root Test to show divergence, note that:

### $\frac{(-1)^n(n^2+1)^n}{(n)^n}$ = $a_n$

You should, after simplification, be able to show that the limit of $a_n$ approaches infinity, which is greater than 1, and so conclude that the series is divergent.

Evaluating the limit algebraically:

### $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$

### $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}|a_n| \ \to \  $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\vert(-1)^n(n^2+1)^n|}{|n^n|} $ $\ \to \ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n^2+1)^n}{n^n} $

Note that the absolute value of $(-1)^n$ is always $1$ as $n \to \infty$ and that as $n \to \infty$, n remains positive

Continuing:

### $= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt[n]{\frac{(n^2+1)^n}{n^n}})$

### $= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac{(n^2+1)}{n}) $

### $= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (n + \frac{1}{n}) \ \to \ +\infty $

As $n$ approaches infinity, $n$ itself becomes larger and larger without bound. It doesn't have an upper limit.

Introducing the $\frac{1}{n}$ term, we are effectively adding an arbitrarily small number, which becomes almost negligible in comparison to the infinitely large value of $n$. Consequently, the limit is evaluated as the expression approaches positive infinity.

Finally, since:  $+\infty$ $\gt$ $1$ The series is shown to be divergent by the Root Test.

Comment: This is the my first answer post, however you can generally tell which test is likely to work based off the context of the series. Here especially it ticked off the boxes for a Root Test: exponents of n, and an alternating term. You would have a lot of trouble using another test. I understand you are likely new to series, but there are helpful flowcharts around that can guide you to the correct test for the series until you get off your feet. But of course tricks don't always work. Good luck!

Comment: @OP: usually when you see something like $\sum(f(n))^n$ where $|f(n)|$ is a sequence whose limit is easy to find, the root test should be your go to, because taking the $n$th root cancels the $n$th power.

Comment: Showing that the limit of $a_n$ is infinity is exactly what the post author said he was struggling with.

Comment: Thank you, it was an oversight, I have since then expanded upon my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Notice,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n^2+1)^n}{(-n)^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(n^2+1)^n}{n^n}$$
where
$$a_n=\frac{(n^2+1)^n}{n^n}\sim\frac{n^{2n}}{n^n}=n^n$$
as $n\to\infty$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$$
as the general term does not tend to $0$ the series is divergent.

---

**Edit**

To add a few more details,
$$(1+n^2)^n=n^{2n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n=n^{2n}\exp n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
which by Taylor's formula,
$$n^{2n}\exp n\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)=n^{2n}\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: You can't invoke the alternating series test to say the series is divergent because that test is a sufficient condition for convergence and not a necessary one. The correct argument would be that $a_n \to 0 \Leftrightarrow (-1)^n a_n \to 0$ and thus the series diverges because its general term does not tend to $0$ when $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: @BrunoB. Thanks for the comment. You are right the test it self doesn't show divergence. I've added in the correct arguments now.

Answer (score 1):

@bob wrote $\frac{(1+n^2)^n}{n^n}\sim \frac{n^{2n}}{n^n}$, but I prefer to be a bit more precise.

Notice
$$(1+n^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}{(n^2)}^k \\ =1+\binom{n}{1}n^2+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}n^{2(n-1)}+n^{2n} \\ \geq n^{2n}$$
Hence

$$\frac{(1+n^2)^n}{n^n}\geq \frac{n^{2n}}{n^n}=n^n$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty }n^n=\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+n^2)^n}{n^n}=\infty$ as well.

Comment: If we are trying to be really precise, you can consider the asymptotic expansion:
$$\frac{(n^2+1)^n}{n^n}=n^n\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\right)$$
as $n\to\infty$.